# apache spark bluemix impossible

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-cloud

I am trying to test the new Apache Spark Starter Boilerplate but I keep receiving error messages. The App gets created with 2 services (Apache Spark and Web Object Storage) but when clicking on the Aoo to launch it, I get the message : app not found . Can you help ?

Comment: You wanna share the error message? And maybe a screen capture of the problem? You really haven't given us anything to go on here to help you.

Answer (score 2):

The Spark Starter boilerplate application was available only during the beta period. Once GA, this service provided the Analytic Notebooks as the replacement.